# How to set web look and feel only for a JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox, look-and-feel

I want to set web look and feel only for a JCombobox in NetBeans.

Image :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking in Swing you can't set the look and feel for any specific component but for the whole set of them. See [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

On the other hand, [WebLaF](https://github.com/mgarin/weblaf) provides extensions for Swing components that have a custom "Look" on their own with no need to set the Look and Feel to WebLaF for the entire application. In this case, instead of using a `JComboBox` you can use `WebComboBox` which is an extension of the previous one. However this custom look is limited and some features such as font (size, weight and family), renderers, pop ups, etc. don't change and still the same of the configured look and feel. So I wouldn't suggest you to do this at all and keep consistency either by setting WebLaf as Look and Feel or by using standard Swing components.

Consider the pictures below (note WebList is broken with Nimbus):

#### MetalLookAndFeel

[image: Metal]

#### NimbusLookAndFeel

[image: Nimbus]

#### WindowsLookAndFeel

[image: Windows]

#### WebLookAndFeel

[image: Web]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this after you set whatever default Swing UI you want and then you will get the WebComboBoxUI for all JComboBoxes only.

```
UIManager.put("ComboBoxUI", "com.alee.laf.combobox.WebComboBoxUI");
```